# AWS - Install the EB CLI on OS X

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to  install the EB CLI with the brew command.

So I run this command:

**$ brew install awsebcli**

It seems that everything is fine but I got an error at the end

```
MacBook-Pro-de-paquirrin:Home paquirrin$ brew install awsebcli
==> Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/a/awsebcli/awsebcli-3.4.4.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100,0%
==> Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/P/PyYAML/PyYAML-3.11.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100,0%
==> python -c import setuptools... --no-user-cfg install --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/aws-elasticbeanstalk/3.4.4/libexec --single-version-externally-managed --record=instal
==> Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/cement/cement-2.4.0.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100,0%
==> python -c import setuptools... --no-user-cfg install --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/aws-elasticbeanstalk/3.4.4/libexec --single-version-externally-managed --record=instal
==> Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/b/backports.ssl_match_hostname/backports.ssl_match_hostname-3.4.0.2.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100,0%
==> python -c import setuptools... --no-user-cfg install --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/aws-elasticbeanstalk/3.4.4/libexec --single-version-externally-managed --record=instal
==> Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pathspec/pathspec-0.3.3.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100,0%
==> python -c import setuptools... --no-user-cfg install --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/aws-elasticbeanstalk/3.4.4/libexec --single-version-externally-managed --record=installed.tx
==> Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/docopt/docopt-0.6.2.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100,0%
==> python -c import setuptools... --no-user-cfg install --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/aws-elasticbeanstalk/3.4.4/libexec --single-version-externally-managed --record=installed.tx
==> Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/requests/requests-2.6.2.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100,0%
==> python -c import setuptools... --no-user-cfg install --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/aws-elasticbeanstalk/3.4.4/libexec --single-version-externally-managed --record=installed.tx
==> Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/t/texttable/texttable-0.8.3.tar.gz

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Error: Failed to download resource "aws-elasticbeanstalk--texttable"
Download failed: https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/t/texttable/texttable-0.8.3.tar.gz
MacBook-Pro-de-paquirrin:Home paquirrin$ eb --version
-bash: eb: command not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are trying to install older version of awsebcli and one of this dependency texttable-0.8.3.tar.gz is no longer available at the specified url

try and upgrade you definitions

```
 brew upgrade awsebcli
 brew install awsebcli
```

More details can be found at

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/FAQ.md

**EDIT**

```
pip install --upgrade awsebcli
```

OR try to upgrade all the brew definition if that is possible for you.

```
brew update && brew upgrade
```

Comment: MacBook-Pro-de-paquirrin:Home paquirrin$  brew upgrade awsebcli
Error: No such file or directory - /usr/local/Cellar/aws-elasticbeanstalk

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me.
Installation:

```
>sudo easy_install pip  
>pip install --upgrade --user awsebcli
```

Now set your python path and path to the eb executable:

```
>cd ~  
>sudo find . -name eb
```

./Library/Python/2.7/bin/eb #mine was found here

```
>vim ~/.bash_profile #if you use bash
```

add below lines to .bash_profile (use your path from sudo find above)
export PYTHONPATH="~/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH"
export PATH=~/Library/Python/2.7/bin:$PATH

```
>. ~/.bash_profile # source the file
```

Try it out:

```
>which eb
```

./Library/Python/2.7/bin/eb #mine prints this path

```
>eb --version # should print the version
```

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes. Saved after hours of research :)

Answer (score 0):

try using `pip` instead like below:

`sudo pip install awsebcli`